# Is it possible to have an SKaction repeat forever only when the sprite is in view of the camera/player?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is for a 2D game:

I have certain quality of life SKactions repeating forever, the two big ones for me are coins rotating/bobbing up and down and water flowing.

According to Apple's documentation, SKactions are instanced. So as long as I have the action subclassed then its only running "once" regardless of how many sprites its being used on. For example, as long as I have all my coins getting their actions from the same "Coin" class, then the memory footprint being used by the coin's action is the same regardless if I have 1 or 20 coins.

All that being said, it seems like such a waste to have these actions going when they aren't even in view of the camera/player.

Is there a way to have repeating forever actions deactivate when they aren't in view of the camera? I know that defeats the purpose of "forever" but as far as I can tell its either choosing some some sort of static duration or choosing forever.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think you understand what the documents are saying.  SKActions are immutable, so when you create an SKAction, you can reuse it on multiple sprites without any fear of the sprite changing it.  The function is still "running" on every coin, but you do not need an instance for every coin.

Comment: as usual, though KoDs suggestion is probably ideal, I may have a simpler (seemingly) but less efficient way to do things. I posit that keeping a dictionary / set / array of nodes with taxing animatons be kept, and then every frame you check if these nodes are in the bounds of your camera.. if so, resume the animation, if not, pause it. I'm guessing this would help performance, but would need to test it.

Comment: also, unrelated, `swift3` tag is for question directly related to the transition from swift2 to swift 3 and so on... the general `swift` tag is what you should be using (and it has many many more followers)

Answer (score 2):

Is better to add node only when is visible, but if you have few nodes, you can use

> func containedNodeSet() -> Set

**Example**

```
class Enemy: SKSprite {
     func startAnimationForever() {
         //do animation if is not already running
     }
     func stopAnimation() {//stop animation}
}
```

in your scene, suppose your cam i `myCam`:

```
//add all enemies in this var or search in the scene all enemy
var allEnemies = Set<Enemy>()

func allVisibleEnemy() ->  Set<Enemy>() {
    let allVisibleEnemy = myCam.containedNodeSet().enumerated().flatMap{node in
         if let enemy = node as? Enemy {
             return enemy
          }
    }
    return Set(arrayLiteral: allVisibleEnemy)
}

func allInvisibleEnemy() ->  Set<Enemy>() {
    let allVisibleEnemy = allVisibleEnemy()
    return allEnemies.substract(allVisibleEnemy)
}

override func update() {
      //all your stuff
      let allVisibleEnemy = getVisibleEnemy()
      let allInvisibleEnemy = allInvisibleEnemy()
      allVisibleEnemy.forEach{enemy in
          enemy.startAnimationForever() 
      }
      allInvisibleEnemy.forEach{enemy in
          enemy.stopAnimation() 
      }
}
```

You can optimizate it if necessary
I've not the compiler, fell free to edit.

Comment: you are restarting your animation every update,  you may need to check if it is not running

Comment: @Knight0fDragon true! This chack can put inside `func startAnimationForever()`

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason you have nodes that are not on the screen that does need to be on the scene for anything, then you should be taking it off the scene to help improve performance.  This would stop actions on the nodes from running, and stop your physics world from having to check if anything physics related needs to placed on it.

Now there are many ways to go about doing this, but a very basic principal would be to establish some kind of map that lays out your nodes (This could be an SKScene that you have not attached to the main scene)  Then use the map(scene) to keep track of all of your nodes. Take your camera and find all the nodes on the map (scene) that is in the view of the camera, and move those nodes over to the main scene.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing the part about have the camera find the nodes and move them to the main scene

Comment: your offscreen scene is a duplicate of your onscreen scene except it houses all nodes. Since it is off screen, it won't process on your main thread, it is simply a memory holder.  So where your camera is on the onscreen scene,  place it on the offscreen scene to find out what nodes belong to your onscreen scene,  all other nodes remove from your onscreen scene unless they need to be there

Comment: what is this concept called so I can look up a tutorial on it?

Comment: ...I don't know if it has a name,  you are just keeping a record of your scene off screen and using what you need on screen

Comment: I know it sounds easy to you, but to me I don't know where to begin on something like that.

Comment: ..... you already have a scene, instead of presenting it on the screen,  just keep it memory.  Present a new scene with nothing on it.  Start your camera off at (0,0) on both off screen and on screen.  Using off screen, grab every node in the camera range.  Move it over to on screen.  At the end (Basically beginning of your next update loop), move all nodes back to off screen.  Repeat process.

Comment: Once you understand it working,  you can optimize so that you do not have to keep moving on and off

Comment: It is a real simple process, do not over think it.

Comment: this is intriguing kod. do you have an example?

Comment: no,  I use advance methods where my scene is broken into segments and I only load segments that I need, I used to do this back in the days when I did gameboy advance development, but my "scene" was a simple map array

Comment: I always thought the overhead of swapping back and forth would be more exhaustive than enumerating which nodes are within the camera bounds... is this wrong? Or is this one and the same?

Comment: in the basic example I have now for the OP,  it is very slow.  The idea is for him to get the concept working, then fine tune it to the point where you are only placing on a few nodes per update.

Comment: enumerating though your nodes would be very slow, especially with a busy scene.  Remember, Sprite Kit nodes are based on a tree structure, so searching for nodes could become very slow since you need to go up and down various branches to find the leaf you are looking for.

Comment: @Fluidity you say this concept is intriguing, do you use a different method?